# create and get Invoice information after one-time payment in stripe

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I'm using spring boot to create session on stripe and validate session after payment is done.

```
createsession()

SessionCreateParams params =
                SessionCreateParams.builder()
                    .addPaymentMethodType(SessionCreateParams.PaymentMethodType.CARD)
                    .setMode(SessionCreateParams.Mode.PAYMENT)
                    .setSuccessUrl("some url")
                    .setCancelUrl("some url")
                    .setClientReferenceId(appProductId)
                    .addLineItem(
                        SessionCreateParams.LineItem.builder()
                            .setQuantity(1L)
                            .setPrice(15*100L)
                            .addTaxRate(taxRate)
                            .build())
                    .build();

            Session session = Session.create(params);
            SessionCreationResponseDto response = new SessionCreationResponseDto();
            response.setId(session.getId());
```

However, I need to get the receipt/invoice for the same. How should I create the invoice in one-time payment in stripe and how will I get the invoice information for later usage (maybe in my application, I need to show a list of downloadable pdf invoices for the account )

any suggestion would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoices are not sent for payments made using `payment` mode in Checkout. You can configure your email settings to automatically send an email receipt after a successful payment: https://stripe.com/docs/receipts

If you need to retrieve a receipt URL at a later date, you can access it from the underlying Charge object: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-receipt_url

Comment: As I see reciept_url is the URL to view the receipt for this charge. But I need something to list in my application, so that user can download the invoice of their payments.

Comment: Stripe doesn't create invoices for one-off charges. A receipt (either generated by Stripe or one you create yourself) can be shared with customers in this case. In your application, you can retrieve all charges for a given customer and use each charge's receipt_url to allow them to download receipts for past payments: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list

Invoices are a separate type of object, and can be created on Stripe as one-off requests for payments, or as part of a subscription.
https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/overview
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in above comment, `Charge` Object -> `receipt_url` worked out in my case. So just adding the code snippet here. However its not an invoice. its just the receipt for the one time payment done on stripe

```
PaymentIntent paymentIntent = PaymentIntent.retrieve(session.getPaymentIntent());
List<String> receipt = paymentIntent.getCharges().getData().stream().map(charge -> charge.getReceiptUrl()).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(receipt.get(0)); // to print the receipt URL
```